# How can create pop up table that is compatible with ios4?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4

I'm doing a testing stuff. I'm making a pop up table (PopUpViewController, UIViewController)  that trigger by UI button through below code. It work fine.

ThirdViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)onClickPopUpView:(id)sender{

    popUpViewController=[[PopUpViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PopUpViewController" bundle:nil];


    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
```

PopUpViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender
{
    [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

That code work for ios5 or later. I wonder how can do some effect that is compatible with ios4. Does anyone give me hint?

Comment: You'd need to do it without UIViewController containment.

Comment: @Jessedc So I need to create UIView and then subclass to ThirdViewController? I'm not sure how to make? Could you please give me some example for reference? Thank in advance.